# Changing iron's pilot lamp connection, will it still work?

Tags: wiring

I have restored a [Rowenta E5291 heavy clothing iron](http://images02.olx.pt/ui/27/43/49/Ferro-engomar-Vintage-Rowenta-E5291T-Povoa-de-Varzim_441503449_2.jpg), a remake of a vintage model, and I changed the pilot lamp's connection.

I made this change because this iron can never be turned off unless you unplug it so I modified the bimetal switch to allow it to be turned off when turning the button to the lowest setting. Everything worked good but it was still heating because the lamp was still directing the power to the heater so I have changed it in the following way:

Diagram of the wiring before and after the modification

[image]

But I am worried that it might blow up the lamp or trigger the breaker box. Since I strongly doubt I can find a replacement for the lamp, in case it gets busted, I would like to hear from anyone if this will work as I expect or if it will cause any problem.

Mind you that I am very amateur but I did check for continuity with a multimeter and everything looked good (Unplugged from the wall).

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Thanks for the heads up, fixed the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modification will work but the sense of the indication changes entirely:

- In original schematic, the lamp would turn on when the switch was off (open), and would turn off when the switch was on (closed).
- In the modified version, the lamp will turn on when the switch is on, and off when the switch is off.

The voltage across the lamp when it is lit would be the same in either case, so the lamp should last as long as in the earlier mode.

Comment: I am not used to irons that work this way so the modification would be a better change and more logical: light turns on when the iron is heating up and working; turns off when it is not working or not heating.

PS: There was a strange behaviour prior to the change: it would heat even if the lamp was off and I don't understand how that happens unless the lamp was allowing enough energy through but not enough to light up and when the bimetal activated it would light up? Makes my head spin.

Comment: @user18715 that's what Anindo is saying - the original behavior is that the iron is on/heating when the light is off (The switch shorts out (turns off) the light *and* turns on the iron.

Comment: @user18715 Yes, it is quite possible that the lamp allows enough current through for the iron to *slooooooowly* heat up over time with the bimetallic switch off. Your modification would prevent that.

Comment: @W5VO Correct me if I am wrong but isn't he actually saying that the light is always on when the switch is closed and open?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Thanks, I will give it a try then in a few hours when the house is empty, to play it safe with the breaker box.

Comment: @user18715 The answer should read correctly now.

Comment: @W5VO I have read your correction to his reply, now it makes more sense (although not so much on the behaviour logic) that the light would turn off when the heater was working, and vice-versa. I am now suspecting that someone has tried to "fix" this iron before and messed up the connections. Will post an update later after my test.

Comment: @user18715 The original behavior is a bit odd - I think I would call it a stand-by indicator (or an `off` light).

Comment: @W5VO Just tested the modification and it worked perfectly, the owner will be very pleased. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have to disagree with you, now the iron is actually more intuitive to use; light is on = heating and iron is working | light is off = not heating and/or iron not working.
And now it can actually be turned off through the button, before it could only be turned off by unplugging it from the wall.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I don't understand what are you talking about. Every modern iron that I have seen works this way, even electric cooking utilities: light turns on whenever it starts heating again, goes off when the correct temperature is reached and it turns on again when the temperature starts dropping. At least in Europe that is the norm, same goes for the switched wall sockets, I have yet to find one house that has them, including the iron's owner. As you might understand, it is way better the way I modified it; more practical and intuitive.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I also suspect that this was the way this iron was built in the first place, and the reason to his different behaviour was because someone messed up the wiring when he tried to fix the iron. Problem is I don't have another iron equal to this one to know how it worked originally.

Comment: @BrianDrummond No worries, it's always good to be challenged, it's the only way to find wether one person is wrong or the other one is. Regardless of the result at least the correct conclusion is reached.